# Cannot find JDK Dependency - JetBrains MPS

Tags: java, mps

I'm watching the first tutorial on [MPS](https://www.jetbrains.com/mps/) over at https://youtu.be/Uq4o4TCLhCQ?t=5m5s and he's talking about adding a dependency (JDK), but when I follow the steps do add it, `JDK` doesn't show up on my list like it does with his list.

I've tried adding other random things from that list which contain `JDK` but, as expected, doesn't help.

How do I add JDK as a dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A silly mistake, but I didn't realise that he had the Solution node highlighted, whereas I had a file highlighted. So right-clicking the solution node > Properties > Dependencies > JDK will show JDK in the list.